# Pythonic way to handle function overloading

Tags: python, overloading

I'm trying to write a function to invert a dictionary but I'm having troubles finding the proper way to do it without rewriting code, using different methods and avoiding if/else at each iteration. What's the most pythonic way to do it?

```
def invert_dict(dic, type=None):
    if type == 'list':
        return _invert_dict_list(dic)
    return _invert_dict(dic)


# if there's only one value per key
def _invert_dict(dic):
    inverted = defaultdict()

    for k,v in dic.items():
        for item in v:
            inverted[item]=k
    return dict(inverted)


# if there are multiple values for the same key
def _invert_dict_list(dic):
    inverted = defaultdict(list)

    for k,v in dic.items():
        for item in v:
            inverted[item].append(k)
    return dict(inverted)
```

Comment: For the `_invert_dict()` method, the `for item in v`, what if the value is the string `'hello'`, are you wanting a `dict` with 5 keys `inverted['h'], inverted['e']`...etc?

Comment: Simple inversion can be accomplished more simply with `{v: k for (k, v) in dic.items()}`.

Comment: Does your solution work the way you want it to? What leads you to believe your solution is *un*-pythonic?

Comment: You may find some inspiration looking at `functools.singledispatch`.

Comment: @wwii it does, but I want to know if there's a better way to do it

Answer (score 1):

I won't comment on the actual impementation, but for the type based branching there is `functools.singledispatch`:

```
import functools

@functools.singledispatch
def inv_item(value, key, dest):
    < fallback implementation >

# special case based on type
@inv_item.register(list)
@inv_item.register(tuple)
def inv_sequence(value, key, dest):
    < handle sequence values >

...

def invert_dict(In):
    Out = {}
    for k, v in In.items():
        inv_item(v, k, Out)
    return Out
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and dictionary comprehension:

```
import itertools 
d1 = {'val1':[4, 5, 2, 4], 13:'v2', 'val2':'v2', 'age':17}
new_d = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted([(b, a) for a, b in d1.items()], key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
final_d = {tuple(a) if isinstance(a, list) else a:[i[-1] for i in b][0] if len([i[-1] for i in b]) == 1 else [i[-1] for i in b] for a, b in new_d}
```

Output:

```
{(4, 5, 2, 4): 'val1', 17: 'age', 'v2': ['val2', 13]}
```